# What's a sane way to do file aging/retention in shell (bash)?

Tags: bash, date, backups

I maintain some backups, daily cron jobs, and I'm looking to implement a more sophisticated system of aging out old archives using just *bash* and common Unix/Linux utilities (such as **GNU** *date*).

The policy I want to implement is something like:

- Keep one for every month, forever
- Keep one per week for 13 weeks (approximately 3 months)
- Remove everything **else** that's older than 14 days

The script I've sketched out maintains these as (hard) links in *./monthly* and *./weekly* (relative to the ***$BASEDIR***).

It looks something like this:

```
#!bash
TSTAMP="$(date +%s-%Y%m%d)"
BASEDIR=/backups
TODAYS="myapp-$TSTAMP.tar.gz"

# If today is 01:
[ "$(date +%d)" = "01" ] && {
   ln "$BASEDIR/$TODAYS" ./monthly/
   ln "$BASEDIR/backup-$TSTAMP.log" ./monthly
   }

# If day of week is 01 (Sunday)
[ "$(date +%w)" = "0" ] && {
   ln "$BASEDIR/$TODAYS" ./weekly
   ln "$BASEDIR/backup-$TSTAMP.log" ./weekly
   }

# Find log from 14 days ago (capture results of glob)                                                                               
f=$(eval echo ./backup-*$(date -d "2 weeks ago" +%Y%m%d)*.log)
# ... but only one match (trim off everything past the space)
f=${f%%" "*}
# If such a file exists: remove all files not newer than it
# but only from .
[ -r "$f" ] && find . -maxdepth 1 -not -newer "$f" -type f \
  | xargs rm
```

But what's a reasonable way to test this for corner cases?  One I can see would be if the backup/log failed to run in a given day (system was down when cron was supposed to run it) ... then the glob will fail to match any file, so the `[ -r "$f" ]` will fail and no trimming will be done.  That seems harmless enough (I get an extra day of backups.  If someone messes up the permissions on the backups then the `-r` could fail even if a matching file is there (but that's a bigger problem).

(Note: this is just the part of the system that prepares local application backup file.  There's a completely different system that gathers them all up on central storage).

It seems like there ought to be a more elegant way to do all this, though!

Is there a `find` like utility which takes some sort of retention specifications and generates a list of files in a tree that **don't** match the specs?

Comment: Why not `mv` the monthly backups into the `./monthly` directory -- that takes care of the keep forever. Write a persistent counter `1...13` to a file. When you get to `13`, remove the oldest file from the `./weekly` folder before `mv`ing the latest into the `./weekly` folder?

Comment: Have you looked at [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)? It's **the**  common Unix/Linux utility used for tasks like this.

Comment: @EdMorton I'd not thought of logrotate for this, even though I've used it for logs forever.  I'll have to think on that.